# Force React Navigation go back without re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, mobile-application, react-native-maps

I am using `DrawerNavigator` from [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation) with Redux for my React Native app (using [Expo](https://expo.io)). My Home screen contains a map (using [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps)). From Home screen, I navigate to a new screen.

Whenever I click the Back button in this new screen to go back to Home screen: `dispatch(NavigationActions.back()`, the Home screen always re-render. Is there any way to go back without re-rendering my Home screen and keep all the states and props unchanged?

Comment: Got kind of the same issue. Did you succeed to find a solution ?

Comment: Actually if you don't want to re-render every component, you should use `StackNavigator`. I think you should nest a `StackNavigator` inside `DrawerNavigator`. In this case, `StackNavigator` will be the the stack that you navigate.

Answer (score 0):

This is an open [issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2277) I think.  Try using a stacknavigator inside the drawernavigator instead.